# Solving a matrix using the differentiation operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L be the operator on $P_3$ defined by

$L(P(x))=xp'(x)+p''(x)$

$(a)$ Find the matrix $A$ representing $L$ with respect to $\left[ 1,x,x^2\right].$

$(b)$ Find the matrix $B$ representing $L$ with respect to $\left[ 1,x,1+x^2\right].$

$(c)$ Find the matrix $S$ such that $B=S^{-1}AS$

$(d)$ If $p(x)= a_0+a_{1}x+a_2(1+x^2),\text{calculate } L^n(p(x))n$

---

EDIT

$$(A) \\ L(1) = 0 \\ 
L(x) =x+0 \\
 L(x^2)=2x^2+2 \\ 
\Rightarrow 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$(B) \\ L(1) = 0 \\ 
L(x) =x+0 \\
 L(1+x^2)=2x^2+2 \\ 
\Rightarrow 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

For part (c) how does one find S? I know one must use the transition matrix from

$\left[ 1,x,x^2\right].$ to$\left[ 1,x,1+x^2\right].$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: The last matrix you wrote has a zero column, so it is definitly not invertable. As you have said, S is the matrix of change of basis (transition matrix) so its columns consist out of the coordinates of the second basis with respect to the first basis

Comment: Student What do they consist of?

Comment: Sorry, i'm typing on mobile, i have edited my comment